# rescale data to era5-land such that the rescaled data is the average of the higher resolution data

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am using google earth engine and the global surface water data and the era5-land data and i want to rescale the global surface water data (30m pixels) to the era5-land data (approximately 9km pixels).

This is what the [`reduceResolution`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-reduceresolution) is supposed to do according to the documentation. However it does not seem to do it. If I toggle `bestEffort` to `true`, as suggested by the documentation, it still doesn't seem to make a difference. How do I rescale this data such that the GSW pixels are averaged together per selection of era5-land pixels?

```
// import data
var gsw_monthly = ee.ImageCollection('JRC/GSW1_4/MonthlyHistory')
print('gsw monthly:', gsw_monthly)

// function to calcilate monthly max vallues within each year
// list of nimbers with years 
var yearlist = ee.List.sequence(2000, 2021) 
var reducer = ee.Reducer.max()

// map over the list of years to generate a composite for each year.
var yearCompList = yearlist.map(function(year){

var yearCol = gsw_monthly.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year'))
var yearMax = yearCol.reduce(reducer);   // reducer

var imgList = yearCol.aggregate_array('system:index');
var n_img = imgList.size();
var nBands = yearMax.bandNames().size();
return yearMax.set({
  'year': year,
  'image_list': imgList,
  'n_bands': nBands,
  'n_img': n_img,
  'method': 'max vallue',
  'system:time_start': year
});
});

// create collection: 
// convert the annual composite image list to an ImageCollection and filter out years with no images.
var annual_max_water = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(yearCompList).filter(ee.Filter.gt('n_bands', 0))
print('annual_max_water', annual_max_water)

// convert to list 
var annual_list = annual_max_water.toList(annual_max_water.size())
print('annual_list', annual_list)

// Map.addLayer(hydrobasins)

var difference = function (img1, img2) {
  // calculates the differences between two images and returns
  // a single image that has the following values
  // -1 -> water disappeared
  //  0 -> no water
  // +1 -> water appeared
  var mask_only_water = function (img) {
    // This function converts the images from the global water resource
    // to only showing where water exists in the data set
    return img.updateMask(img.eq(2)).multiply(0).add(1).unmask(0)
    // return img.lte(1).multiply(0).divide(2)
  }
  var img1_mask = mask_only_water(img1)
  var img2_mask = mask_only_water(img2)
  var diff = img2_mask.subtract(img1_mask).copyProperties(img1_mask, ['max vallue', 'n_img', 'system:time_start', 'year'])
  var img_diff = ee.Image(diff)
  return img_diff
}

var year1L = 2000
var year2L = 2021
// var filename = '2001_2002'

var imgtest1 = ee.Image(annual_list.get(year1L-2000))
print(imgtest1)
var imgtest2 = ee.Image(annual_list.get(year2L-2000))

var diff = difference(imgtest1, imgtest2)
print(diff)
// Map.addLayer(diff)
// Map.addLayer(imgtest2, {palette: ["ff440c","0aff4a","fbff0c","f116ff"],max: 2, min: 0, opacity: 1})
// Map.addLayer(imgtest2, one_year_params)
Map.addLayer(diff.updateMask(diff.neq(0)), {palette: ['red',  'cyan']}, 'difference 2012')


var dataset = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY")
                .filter(ee.Filter.date('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31')
                ).first()).select('total_precipitation_hourly');
print('dataset',dataset)
var proj = dataset.projection()
print('proj',proj)

// print(dataset['total_precipitation'])

var visualization = {
  bands: ['total_precipitation_hourly'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.05,
  palette: [
    "#000080","#0000D9","#4000FF","#8000FF","#0080FF","#00FFFF",
    "#00FF80","#80FF00","#DAFF00","#FFFF00","#FFF500","#FFDA00",
    "#FFB000","#FFA400","#FF4F00","#FF2500","#FF0A00","#FF00FF",
  ]
};

// Map.setCenter(22.2, 21.2, 0);

Map.addLayer(dataset, visualization, "precip");
// Map.getScale();


var lakeMean = diff.setDefaultProjection(proj).reduceResolution({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      maxPixels: 65535
    }).reproject({
      crs: proj
    });
print(lakeMean)
    
Map.addLayer(lakeMean, {}, 'lakes mapped to era5')
```

Comment: in the gee developer forums it says that it might be a bug and that it uses the center pixel instead of the mean https://groups.google.com/g/google-earth-engine-developers/c/jDkBV1kcN98/m/OS3IGfy6AAAJ